# How to filter and remove standard http headers from response entity headers?

Tags: java, spring-boot, http-headers, resttemplate

I am calling some rest endpointusing rest template in spring boot as below:

```
ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(url, httpMethod, entity, String.class);
```

And than i am reading all headers from response entity like below:

```
HttpHeaders httpHeaders = responseEntity.getHeaders();
```

**But HttpHeaders contains so many headers, from from these i only want to read headers which are custom headers, and we do not know the custom header names, s obasically i just want to remove all standard HTTP headers and get all remaining headers.**

**How can we remove all standard HTTP headers?**

**`Apart from creating an array of all known headers from elements of HttpHeaders class, is there any other way to get list of all known http headers?`**

Answer (score 0):

The Map class has a remove() method. You could iterate over a list of all known headers, removing each of them. What is left would be your custom headers.

Alternately you could use the toCommaDelimitedString method on HttpHeaders, and then iterate over that removing all known headers.

Comment: Iteration is not the concern here, i am concern about how to remove list on all the HTT headers.

Comment: Right, so make a list of all know headers. Iterate over that list and remove each from your HttpHeaders. There isn't a built in method to remove them.

Comment: https://github.com/danielmiessler/SecLists/blob/master/Miscellaneous/web/http-request-headers/http-request-headers-fields-large.txt

Comment: How to get this list in Java? without creating it manually?

Answer (score 0):

class HttpHeaders defined All standard HTTP headers Key，so what you need to do is provide a method to filter out custom headers your expect

Comment: Yes, i also thought of the same but there are so many headers defined in HttpHeaders  class, so is there list or array of all these heders available?? else i would need to create manually one array and what if there is one more header added in that class, how would i know ??

Comment: 1、the kind of http headers  change ought in  the future  is Minimal probability , and also the http lib .  
2、I suggest create manually  `Hashset`  , use it's `Contains` is O(1).